# Laravel - php artisan migrate issue - driver not found - ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-artisan

I am using xampp in ubuntu, while i do php artisan migrate, it showed `PDO Exception could not find driver`

Then to fix that

I showed me to install mbstring, php_curl etc., i have installed mbstring, then while install php_curl i got error can't locate

```
root@allau-Inspiron-5558:/home/allau# sudo apt-get install php5-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5-curl
```

when i type php --ini it showed the following

```
root@allau-Inspiron-5558:/home/allau# php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
```

But i am using xampp in ubuntu, i guess it points the php.ini of /etc/php/7.0 but i want to use php of /opt/lampp how can i do that ?

help pls

Comment: If you want to change what PHP it uses, add it to your path, so modify ~/.bashrc and add the path to the php you want to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP that you are using via CLI is different from the one that is being used by XAMPP. XAMPP brings its own PHP, and if you want to run that one via CLI instead the one that you probably got with Ubuntu, then you should add it to your PATH:

`nano ~/.bashrc`

Then add this line at the end of the file:

`export PATH=/opt/lampp/bin:$PATH`

...and save it (`ctrl+o` -> `enter` -> `ctrl+x`)